# How to apply a function to sub selections in a pandas DataFrame object efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of people's addresses and names. I have a function that processes names that I want to apply. I am creating sub selections of people with matching addresses and applying the function to those groups.

To this point I have been using `.loc` to as follows

```
for x in df['address'].unique():
   sub_selection = df.loc[df['address'] == x]
   sub_selection.apply(lambda x: function(x), axis = 1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to approach this. I am looking into pandas .groupby() functionality, but i am struggling to get it to work.

```
df.groupby('address').agg(lambda x: function(x['names']))
```

Here is some sample data:

```
address, name, Unique_ID

1022 Boogie Woogie Ave, John Smith, np.nan
1022 Boogie Woogie Ave, Frederick Smith, np.nan
1022 Boogie Woogie Ave, John Jacob Smith, np.nan
3030 Sesame Street, Big Bird, np.nan
3030 Sesame Street, Elmo, np.nan
3030 Sesame Street, Big Yellow Bird, np.nan
```

My function itself has some moving parts, but basically I check the name against a reference dictionary I create. This process passes a few other steps, but returns a list of indexes where the name matches. I use those indexes to assign a shared unique id for matching names. In my example big bird and big yellow bird would match.

```
def function(x):
    match_list = []
    if x['name'] in __lookup_dict[0]:
        match_list.append((__lookup_dict[0][x['name']))
    #reduce all elements matching list to a single list of place ids matching all elements
    result = set(match_list[0])
    for s in match_list[1:]:
        if len(result.intersection(s)) != 0:
            result.intersection_update(s)
    #take the reduce lists and assign each place id an unique id. 
    #note we are working with place ids not the sub df's index. They don't match
    if pd.isnull(x['Unique_ID']):
        uid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        for g in result:
            df.at[df.index[df.index == g].tolist()[0], 'Unq_ID'] = uid
    else:
        pass
    return result
```

Comment: Could you share specifics on what's not working? Some example data would be helpful too!

Comment: Surely, i am struggling to pass a function to the groupby object to run the function on all the sub selections independently. The initial function I posted works, but it is very slow, and I am working with datasets of millions of records. The basics of the function is to match people's names, and I only care to match names if people share the same address. So specifically with the groupby function, it only appears to accept vectorized functions (i may be wrong here), and my function is not meant to be vectorized. So the function itself is not passing through to the object

Comment: Got it, thanks! I'd really need to see a self-contained, runnable example including data and the definition of `function`.

Comment: I have appended the question. I tried to strip down the function to the relevant steps. Just let me know if anything is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
df.groupby('address').apply(lambda x: function(x['names']))
```

**Edited:**
Check this example. I've used a dataframe from another StackOverflow question

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "City":["Delhi","Delhi","Mumbai","Mumbai","Lahore","Lahore"],
    "Points":[90.1,90.3,94.1,95,89,90.5],
    "Gender":["Male","Female","Female","Male","Female","Male"]
})

d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(df.City.unique())}
df['idx'] = df['City'].replace(d)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     City  Points  Gender  idx
0   Delhi    90.1    Male    0
1   Delhi    90.3  Female    0
2  Mumbai    94.1  Female    1
3  Mumbai    95.0    Male    1
4  Lahore    89.0  Female    2
5  Lahore    90.5    Male    2
```

So, try using

```
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(df['address'].unique())}
df['idx'] = df['address'].replace(d)
```

Comment: When I run that, i get the following: TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'. I don't the groupby object is accepting the .apply method

Comment: I've removed `axis`. Could you specify what `function` does?

Comment: Yes, the function matches names through an array of processing steps and assigns a unique id to matching names. As I only care to match names with the same address, I only want to process names within a sub selection of addresses. Because the function needs to run iteratively, i would need the same functionality as the axis =1 parameter. Regardless, when I try to pass the function calling the specific field names to the groupby object, it is not reading the field names. For example, it will not read the owner's name field, which is a parameter of my function.

Comment: So i think I am just utilizing this groupby object incorrectly

Comment: @Vance I've edited the answer according to the task. I hope I got it right

Comment: So this is assigning a unique id based on the addresses. From here, I need to pass the records in the sub selection of the address through a function to see if the names match. In your example, the Delhi | Male record would receive a different 'idx than the Delhi | Female record. unfortunately I am using a fuzzy matching technique to match the names, so I have to pass the names through a function to see if they match before assigning ids